# Linking static libraries libm.a or libc.a with NDK cmake

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, cmake, clang

Is it possible to link platforms\android-XX\arch-arm\usr\lib*.a versions of libraries when using NDK Cmake build system with Android Studio? I'm using LLVM toolchain and Android NDK 13.

I have tried modifications on sample app, changing file: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/blob/master-cmake/hello-jni/app/src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt

With following modification (adding libm.a):

```
target_link_libraries(hello-jni libm.a android log)
```

Builds successfully, but readelf -d reveals that libm.so is still linked:

```
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libandroid.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [liblog.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libm.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libdl.so]
 0x00000001 (NEEDED)                     Shared library: [libc.so]
```

When adding also libc.a it gets worse, building fails:

```
Error:error: relocation overflow in R_ARM_THM_JUMP11
Error:error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

BTW, sometimes I see only last error without any explanation (for example, when misspelling library name). Should I set -v flag somehwere to see more details? How to do it?

Comment: Just FYI, statically linking libc into your app will be painful. The Zygote will have it's own duplicate copy of the same global data and the two will be in conflict.

Comment: @DanAlbert I see. Just to be clear, are you talking about some global data used internally in libc.a which is used indirectly and shared by users of library?

Comment: Maybe it's possible to link somehow only necessary parts from static library and avoid problems with global data? I think with static linking linker imports only necessary things.

Comment: "Necessary things" in terms of the C runtime includes the global data. We do have plans for making something like this work in the NDK (so you can access new libc features on old devices), but it's not ready yet. It's possible that using static libc in an app is less disastrous than I expect. I honestly haven't tried, but similar things I've tried did have this problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you're just wanting to get this to compile,  I'd try to use arm-linux-androideabi-gcc instead of clang.  I realize that gcc is depreciated.  But I can't if your goal is to compile or understand the problem. Judging from Dan's comment, I'm assuming that he doesn't believe any of the the flags he commented on in aosp will help (see link below)

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/build/+/master/core/clang/config.mk

FWIW, I tend to always use static libs from aosp/bionic builds I do because I work on numerous things that require them.  there tends to be too much inconsistency in symbols included in bionics libc between sdk versions, that and for statically linking its required to use libc.a for the most part I believe. If you're going to use a ndk version of a static libc,  I would suggest using platform 21 instead of 24.

I figure that since Android is so fragmented, and all devices use different libc.so, libdl.so, etc that it can't cause too many issues.

EDIT: misread the question.

Comment: Turns out I set minSdkVersion to 15 in build.gradle(app), so linker tried to link libc.a from that folder. When switched minSdkVersion to 21 correct libc.a version was used and everything compiled successfully, though readelf still shows libc.so but I guess it's because other parts of native library require that. But loading of shared library fails both with gcc and clang - only when static libc.a is used:
`SIGSEGV (signal SIGSEGV: address access protected (fault address: 0x206e7777))`
I guess it's because static version of libc conflicts with shared one as mentioned by Dan.

Comment: If you are making a shared library,  you can't link with libc.a,  you have to use libc.so (well you can,  but it's not a good idea,  like Dan said) ,  sorry I thought you were making an executable file.   Just so I understand,  why do you want to use static libs when making a shared library? Honestly you could probabaly include static versions of all of those needed libraries,  except for libc.  But again I'm not sure on the reasoning for wanting to link them statically if your goal is to make a shared lib.

Comment: Ultimate goal was also to convert *.so to *.a also. I would like to have static linking just to avoid easy overriding of C functions (like memcpy, etc) when someones tries to abuse my library. Because those functions operate on data I would like to hide. What's the difference between linking static library to executable or shared library in this context?